# How to add an ArrayList<Integer> to an ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> again and again with different elements in ArrayList<Integer>

Tags: java, arraylist

I have created an ArrayList of ArrayList in java. And iam storing values in them as follows :

```
import java.util.ArrayList;


    class Test {
        public static void main(String args[]) {
                ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> connections = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>();
                ArrayList<Integer> currentConnects = new ArrayList<>();
                currentConnects.add(7);
                currentConnects.add(4);
                connections.add(currentConnects);
                currentConnects.clear();
                currentConnects.add(10);
                currentConnects.add(15);
                connections.add(currentConnects);
                System.out.println(connections);
        }
    }
```

I am expecting the output to be :

```
[[7, 4], [10, 15]]
```

but the output is  :

```
[[10, 15], [10, 15]]
```

How can i achieve my expected output without using any other extra variables?

Comment: Hint: You are adding the same `ArrayList<Integer>` twice instead of two different ones.

Comment: @ray get your nose checked :p sorry but it wasn't a homework . i was stuck and i presented my efforts (clear() method) and seeking for help. I guess this is what stackoverflow is for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're actually referencing the same object twice in your `connections` object, hence the result you have.

Instead of `currentConnects.clear();` try `currentConnects = new ArrayList<>();`

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove  currentConnects.clear(); and create a new ArrayList Object.Your ArrayList objects are pointing to the same Object in heap.The `ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>` contains same reference of ArrayList twice

import java.util.ArrayList;

```
    class Test {
        public static void main(String args[]) {
                ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> connections = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>();
                ArrayList<Integer> currentConnects = new ArrayList<>();
                currentConnects.add(7);
                currentConnects.add(4);
                connections.add(currentConnects);

                currentConnects = new ArrayList<>();
                currentConnects.add(10);
                currentConnects.add(15);
                connections.add(currentConnects);
                System.out.println(connections);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to create new array lists everytime.

When you do:

```
  connections.add(currentConnects);
  currentConnects.clear();
```

You first add a reference of currentConnects, and then clear the content of currentConnects, you are not creating a new arraylist. Instead do:

```
  ArrayList<Integer> currentConnects = new ArrayList<>();
  currentConnects.add(7);
  currentConnects.add(4);
  connections.add(currentConnects);
  currentConnects = new ArrayList<>();
  currentConnects.add(10);
  currentConnects.add(15);
  connections.add(currentConnects);
```

Answer (score 0):

When you call `connections.add(currentConnects);`, since `connections` is of type `ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>`, you're actually adding a reference to entire ArrayList connections, **NOT**  just the integers in the ArrayList itself.

So because you call `connections.add(currentConnects);` twice, there are two references to `connections` ArrayList, which is why the integers held in `connections` are printed out twice.